# Update is not a known function on Bounds in version 3.32 of Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The typescript code below compiles, but bounds is getting a runtime error suggesting that update is not a known function.

```
var bounds = self.esriHelper.requireModule('esri/geometry/Extent');
bounds = bounds.update ( -60836536.56026919, -42677544.62462127, 342437.88671754766, 8169589.583117515, self.spatialReference);
```

This code was originally on version 3.18 of ESRI's Javascript API. I upgraded to 3.32 and added the two lines above to create a map without a basemap

```
self.map = new Map('map', {
  extent: bounds,
  sliderPosition: 'top-right',
  logo: false
});
```

I am new to javascript and working on inherited code. I also tried
`import {Extent} from 'esri/geometry/Extent';`
without success.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what is `self.esriHelper.requireModule`, it seems like an util function to load modules. If that's the case then the return is a class not an object. `Extent` `update` function works on an extent object, because it updates the values of the caller, in other words it doesn't work on a class.

You need something like this,

```
var esriGeometryExtent = self.esriHelper.requireModule('esri/geometry/Extent');
bounds = new esriGeometryExtent( -60836536.56026919, -42677544.62462127, 342437.88671754766, 8169589.583117515, self.spatialReference);
```

Again, I am supposing that `self.esriHelper.requireModule` is a function that loads a module, and that it resolves correctly the async logic.